# HTTP + swagger in logic app - parsing the schema

Tags: json, azure, azure-functions, swagger, azure-logic-apps

I am using HTTP+Swagger to make API call(hosted in APIM gateway) in logic app.

In Logic app we can use the parse Json to parse the schema and it provide us access to the individual element of the JSON payload(which we can use in downstream logic). But we have to manually paste the schema in the schema field of parseJson activity.

I want to automate the process. I am looking a way where I can collect the Json schema in a variable and then parse my Json through this variable(schema). This will help me not to make manual interferences  with logic app in case of change in schema.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have to manually write the JSON schema but you just need a sample of the JSON that you want to parse. Consider here is some sample

```
[
  {
    "document": "A",
    "min": 7500001,
    "policy": "X"
  },
  {
    "document": "B",
    "min": 7500001,
    "policy": "Y"
  },
  {
    "document": "C",
    "min": 7500001,
    "policy": "Z"
  },
{
    "document": "D",
    "min": 7500002,
    "policy": "X"
  }
]
```

So you need to use `Use sample payload to generate schema`.

[image]

[image]

and then you will be automatically have generated schema

[image]

Below is the generated schema

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "document": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "min": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "policy": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "document",
            "min",
            "policy"
        ]
    }
}
```

### Updated Answer

---

So, This would work even when you have a JSON change just remove the required from the schema and this would work perfectly when you are trying to use the same parameters as before.

For example, I have changed my sample to

```
[
  {
    "document": "A",
    "min": 7500001,
    "sample":"test1"
  },
  {
    "document": "B",
    "min": 7500001,
    "sample":"test2"
  },
  {
    "document": "C",
    "min": 7500001,
    "policy": "Z"
  },
{
    "document": "D",
    "min": 7500002,
    "policy": "X"
  }
]
```

and remain the schema to be the same as before, this would fail due to schema validation

[image]

but when you just remove the required from schema i.e.,

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "document": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "min": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "policy": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Swetha, But My ask is if In future  the json schema changes we need to again generate the schema from the payload(as you did), this is a manual intervention in case of schema change. I want to avoid manually generating the schema. I want to find any way where if schema changes i dont have to change any bit of code myself.

Comment: @Deepak So to stop failing the logic app due to schema validation you can just remove the required section from the schema so that it will never fail the run. For more details Can you please check the updated answer

Comment: This can be a possibility but  not in my case - I am having complex nested Json and I am expecting the Json structure to be changing so removing the required section will not help ! . But thanks again for prompt reply.